# How to make a custom action bar for just copy the text?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-edittext, custom-controls

I have an edit text as output of my results and it's editable text, so the user by long click can cut, copy, and paste the text.. So i need to code my app to show action bar for long click so the user can only copy the text !!
i see this code in the questions, but some functions are missed in the code :

```
VancoSR.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new    View.OnLongClickListener() 
{

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View p1)
        {
            // TODO: Implement this method
            startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
            return false;
        }
    });
 }

class ActionBarCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback
{


@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
{           
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.copyText:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.pasteText:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Paste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.cutText:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Help",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return true;
    }
    return false;

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create items in actionbar and set their `visibility` to `invisible`. Then on long click make them `visible`. Then you already have your code in `onActionItemSelected` method. Hide them again when you exit the method.

Comment: this is not my code as i said before ! so i don't have the items, i don't know how to make a copy function only ?!

Comment: Are you asking for a function to get text in the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a try to implement the Contextual Action Bar (CAB).

I think it's a good starting point learning the associated design pattern [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html). Implementation guidance you will find [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB).

Hope it helps you!